# Swagger codegen generates duplicated variables

Tags: java, http, yaml, swagger, swagger-codegen

I'm trying to generate client from yaml that contains

```
  acceptParam:
    name: Accept
    type: string
    required: true
    in: header
    description: Accepted Content-type. Should be set to application/json
  contentTypeParam:
    name: Content-Type
    type: string
    required: true
    in: header
    description: Request Content-type. Should be set to application/json
```

That means, `accept` and `contentType` will be present in generated method signature.

On top of that, I'v configured plugin like this

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.swagger.codegen.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.18</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/swagger.yaml</inputSpec>
                <language>java</language>
                <configOptions>
                    <dateLibrary>joda</dateLibrary>
                    <localVarPrefix>localVar</localVarPrefix>
                </configOptions>
                <library>resttemplate</library>
                <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</output>
                <modelPackage>com.example.client.model</modelPackage>
                <apiPackage>com.example.client.api</apiPackage>
                <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Still, after `mvn clean install`

I'm getting

> Error:(130,31) java: variable accept is already defined in method

And generated code contains

```
public Response authorize(Request body, String accept, ...) {
   ....
   final List<MediaType> accept = apiClient.selectHeaderAccept(accepts);    
   ....
}
```

I'v tried different versions of plugin (from 2.3.0 up to newest one), after overcoming lots of other issues, I'm always ending up like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenAPI 2.0, the `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers should be defined using `consumes` and `produces` rather than parameters. In OpenAPI 3.0, these headers are defined as request/response media types.

Change your operation definition as follows:

```yaml
swagger: '2.0'

paths:
  /foo:
    post:
      consumes:
        - application/json
      produces:
        - application/json
      ...
```

or if you use OpenAPI 3.0:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0

paths:
  /foo:
    post:
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:     # <----
            schema:
              ...
      responses:
        '200':
          description: ok
          content:
            application/json:   # <----
              schema:
                ...
```

Comment: Well, that explains a lot, too bad thats not my API. Hopefully, once I reach it's developer he will fix that...

Answer (score 5):

A bit late to the party, but I had the same issue using a 3rd party API, and this is the first question that appears on a search. The openapi yaml seemed valid in my case, and since it was 3rd party, changing it wasn't viable anyway. I had to use localVariablePrefix (with variable completely spelled out).

So to modify your pom.xml:

```
<configOptions>
    <dateLibrary>joda</dateLibrary>
    <localVariablePrefix>localVar</localVariablePrefix>
</configOptions>
...
```

Comment: Some detail missing from the answer that would help. `configOptions` is a child of `configuration`.